# Return inserted row

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I return the row I just inserted including DB-generated identifier?
My SQL is just a standard dynamic SQL insert

```
insert into dbo.TableName (Col1, Col2) values (@Col1, @Col2);
```

I have tried select from inserted, but inserted object is not a known object

```
insert into dbo.TableName (Col1, Col2) values (@Col1, @Col2); select * from inserted;
```

I have tried using output, but I cannot do that, when there is a trigger on the table

```
insert into dbo.TableName (Col1, Col2) output inserted.* values (@Col1, @Col2);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to place a `commit` between the `insert` and the consecutive `select`? You could re-write the query to make it return the most recently inserted value...

Comment: I just tried adding a begin transaction and then a commit after my insert before the select. Makes no difference

Comment: What do you mean you cannot use `output` when there is a trigger?  That is actually the SAFEST time to use `output` -- unless you want an id from *another* table.

Comment: I see the error message: "The target table 'dbo.TableName' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.)'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could insert the row and then use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the ID of the row you inserted and return the row with that id from the table.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES (a1, a2);

DECLARE @Id INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE ID = @Id
```

Comment: I suppose I could make something in that style work. I was hoping for something simpler though. Problem is I am writing a generic library to access SQL.The SQL I generate would then look something like yours, if the key is a DB-generated key, but very different if it is not.

Comment: @TorbenNielsen In that case I would simply suggest that after the insert, you then query the selected table for the values you have inserted, depending on if the values are distinct or not.

Comment: That is actually a great idea. And in the where condition for any DB-generated field, I could use SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause:

```
--Sample table
CREATE TABLE IdentityInsert
(
    ID int IDENTITY,
    A int
)

INSERT IdentityInsert OUTPUT inserted.* VALUES (3)
```

Comment: How is this different from their third code sample which already contains `OUTPUT inserted.*` ?

Comment: As I wrote in my post, this will not work when there is a trigger on the table

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to ask SQL Server which row was inserted last unless you are doing so in the same batch as the insert. For example, if your table has an IDENTITY column, you can use SCOPE_IDENTITY() (never use @@IDENTITY, since that can be unreliable if you have or will ever add triggers to the source table):

```
INSERT dbo.table(column) SELECT 1;
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

More generally, you can use the OUTPUT clause, which doesn't rely on an IDENTITY column (but will still make it difficult to identify which row(s) the clause identifies if there is no PK):

```
INSERT dbo.table(column) OUTPUT inserted.* SELECT 1;
```

If you're not talking about the same batch, then the only real way to identify the last row inserted is to use a date/time column where the timestamp of insertion is recorded. Otherwise it is like you emptied a bag of marbles on the floor, then asked someone to enter the room and identify which one hit the floor last.

You may be tempted or even advised to use the IDENT_CURRENT() function, but I explain here why this is unreliable too.

You could add a column to track this going forward:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.table ADD DateInserted DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Now you can find the last row(s) inserted by simply:

```
;WITH x AS (SELECT *, r = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DateInserted DESC)
   FROM dbo.table)
SELECT * FROM x WHERE r = 1;
```

(If you don't want ties, you can add a tie-breaking column to the ORDER BY, or you can simply change RANK() to ROW_NUMBER() if you don't care which of the tied rows you get.)

You might make the assumption that the last row inserted is the highest identity value, but this isn't necessarily the case. The identity can be reseeded and it can also be overridden using SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON;.

Comment: OUTPUT inserted.* will not work when there is a trigger on the table (as I wrote in my post). And yes... It is in the same batch